# Trying to extract a row of data from Parse into an array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to pull data from a Parse class into my Swift project. I'm struggling in general because I'm still learning, but I've at least gotten to the point where the query executes successfully and returns a result. The problem is that the data only exist within the for loop that loops through objects. Attempts to append an array or set a variable to the Parse object value have failed. Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
//Declare variables that should exist outside the query
    var parseArray : [Double] = Array() //the array to store the results
    var parseResult1 : Double = Double() //the variable to store one of the data points from the parse class
    let parseResults = PFObject(className:"parseResults")

    //declare query variable and run query
    let parseResultsQuery = PFQuery(className:"parseResults")
    parseResultsQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
        parseResultsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects!{ //looping through returned data
                    print("no error in Parse lookup")
                    parseResult1 = object["parseResult1"] as! Double
                    print("Parse result in object loop: \(parseResult1)")
                    parseArray.append(parseResult1)
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    print("Parse result outside of loop: \(parseResult1)")
    print(parseArray)
```

The parseResult1 variable shows the value while in the "for object in objects" loop (e.g. 7.0) but outside of the loop the value is not stored and appears as 0.0. Ideally I would like to store all the Parse values that match the username key in a Swift array, but I would settle for pulling the objects out one by one at this point!

Comment: You have the closure `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error: NSError?) -> Void in`. When you call it, the program dont wait it ending and gose next. Your `parseResult1` is a local object and when you closure body caled, you alredy went from the paren method and when you exit from closure body the local objects are destroyed and it is not save your parse data. You need create your objects like global for function wich code you write here

Answer (score 0):

You have the closure:

```
... findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error: NSError?) -> Void in...
```

When you call it, the program don't wait it ending and gose next. 
Your objects:

```
var parseArray : [Double] = Array() //the array to store the results
var parseResult1 : Double = Double() //the variable to store one of the data points from the parse class
let parseResults = PFObject(className:"parseResults")
```

are local objects for it function and when your closure body called, you alredy went from the parent method and when you exit from closure body the local objects are destroyed and it is not save your parse data. You need create your objects like global for function wich code you write here.

Answer (score 0):

Take the parsing logic out of the closure and call a private method, passing the objects property to that. Better form and will take care of your issue:

```
func parseResults(objects: Array<PFOject>){

    for object in objects!{ //looping through returned data
                    print("no error in Parse lookup")
                    parseResult1 = object["parseResult1"] as! Double
                    print("Parse result in object loop: \(parseResult1)")
                    parseArray.append(parseResult1)
    }

}
```

Then call that in the closure after checking for an error.

Note: untested code - may need some minor tweaks.

Comment: No problem - when you get a chance, please accept the answer. Thanks!! :)